# Why is my drop down menu hovering sideways rather than listing downwards?

Tags: html, css

hey so i made a website homepage and i added a navigation bar, but one little problem is blowing my mind and i cant seem to get around it. i have added a hover effect and a drop down menu to one of the links . it works okay but the drop down menu is displayed along side the drop down link. i cant seem to get it to drop below the link like a normal drop down menu. please tell me where i have gone wrong.

HTML:

```
<!--Navigation bar-->
    <div id="Navbar">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Info</a>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a>Support</a></li>
                         <li><a>Privacy</a></li>
                         <li><a>Terms</a></li>
                         <li><a>Cookies</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#Navbar
{
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #0009;
    line-height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 1;
}

nav ul
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

nav ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #A52A2A;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

nav ul li ul li
{
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li
{
    display: block;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update your code with minor changes, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
#Navbar
{
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #0009;
    line-height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 1;
}

nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    padding: 22px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li:hover > a
{
    background-color: #A52A2A;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="Navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Info</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a>Support</a></li>
             <li><a>Privacy</a></li>
             <li><a>Terms</a></li>
             <li><a>Cookies</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

**HTML**

```
<!--Navigation bar-->
    <div id="Navbar">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                 <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Info</a>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a>Support</a></li>
                         <li><a>Privacy</a></li>
                         <li><a>Terms</a></li>
                         <li><a>Cookies</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
#Navbar
{
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #0009;
    line-height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 1;
}

nav ul
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

nav ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #A52A2A;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

nav ul li ul
{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
}
nav ul li.submenu{
  position:relative;
}
nav ul li.submenu:hover ul{
   display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li
{

    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code i have added a class for drop-down and set its position.

```css
#Navbar
{
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #0009;
  line-height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0; 
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul
{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

nav ul li > ul.dropdown_menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li
{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a
{
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

nav ul li ul li
{
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li
{
  display: block;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Info</a>
        <ul class="dropdown_menu">
          <li><a>Support</a></li>
          <li><a>Privacy</a></li>
          <li><a>Terms</a></li>
          <li><a>Cookies</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: open this output in full screen.